# Part of Linux removed by apt install

Tags: apt, system-recovery

was trying to install wine on linux(parrot) and there were some dependancies. I am not sure of the exact name but of the package but it started with lib and had i386 in the name. I tried to install it with apt using the -f tag. I was stupid and didnt read the big message and it started deleting a lot of things of my computer and I assume it was going to reinstall them in 32 bit. However there was a problem and it stopped at less than 50 percent. I tried do use the same apt command again but it had unistalled something and it wasn't even starting. From what I saw there is no network manager in /etc/unit.d

The computer cannot boot in graphical mode and I cannot enter the text mode. When I booted with recover, it said /etc/init isn't found and that /bin/init also isn't found. It then has a message kernel panic - not syncing attempted to kill knit.

I am sorry if am not explaining it good please ask if I should add more information.

I don't know if there is any way to recover or if I should get a new linux disk and migrate my info. If I do have to do this how to I pull out my info? Onto a usb?

I have dual boot Windows alongside Linux if it will help. Maybe mounting a folder and pulling my data out.

Comment: Wait, what? You were trying to install a 32-bit Windows operating system on Linux? That... doesn't make sense. In any case, I am afraid we cannot help if you can't tell us what you actually did and what specific commands you ran. Also, from what you describe, it really sounds like you should just reinstall and restore your data from backup.

Comment: I had a software I wanted to install however it was only available in  .exe files. There is a package called wine which can execute and install  .exe files on linux systems. The above describes what happened when I tried to install the package called wine.